# v-for item type is unknown

Tags: typescript, vuejs3, v-for

In VS Code Typescript throws errors. Apparently item is of type unknown. But it renders fine and there are no errors or warnings in console. How do I get rid of those errors?

```
<script setup lang="ts">
    import NavLink from '@/Components/NavLink.vue';
    import { PropType } from 'vue'

    interface Item {
        href: String,
        active: Boolean,
        text: String
    }

    const props = defineProps({
        items : {
            type: Object as PropType<Item[]>,
            required: true
        }
    });
</script>

<template>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg">
            <div class="container">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="{{route('dashboard')}}">Page title</a>
                <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation"><span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span></button>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                    <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
                        <NavLink v-for="(item, key, index) in items" :href="item.href" :active="item.active" :key="index">
                            {{item.text }}
                        </NavLink>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
</template>
```

Errors:

- Property 'href' does not exist on type 'unknown'.
- Property 'active' does not exist on type 'unknown'.
- Property 'text' does not exist on type 'unknown'.

Comment: [Please replace/supplement images of code/errors with plaintext versions.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/2887218)

Comment: I did not downvote your question; in fact, I very rarely downvote, and usually only in the relatively unusual situation where a problem cannot be otherwise resolved (say by comments or editing). I hope you'll refrain from making such assumptions in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is strange.

The `items` props is declared as `type: Object as PropType<Item[]>` - so runtime type (information Vue uses to handle the props) is Object but type info says it is an array. Seems incorrect and possibly the reason why Volar (Vue VS COde language service) is perplexed

Comment: It's the same if I use `type: Array as PropType<Item[]>` or `type: Array<PropType<Item[]>>`